# Android 2.3.3 tablet can't find external SD card

Tags: external-sd

I have a no-name Chinese tablet. When first purchased, I took three pics and everything seemed fine. The problem is when I went to use the camera later and it requested I to insert or mount an SD Card. Gallery would say no pictures. Application Manager would not move apps to the SD card.

I reformatted the SD card and everything worked for 10 minutes taking pictures. Gallery would show taken pics. Application manager would move apps to SD card. Then bam, everything back to "Please insert SD card". In Application Manager, tapping on an application/Move to SD card would not work. Camera asks for SD card to be inserted, Downloaded apps from Google Play would not install asking for an SD card.

I emailed the problem and was told by Factory to Format Nand and so I did. Things work for a while then back to the same thing, "please insert SD card". Apps won't download or move. Reformatting Nand erases Gallery and many downloaded apps so I lose all my pictures and programs.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the ext SD card is not mounting after a while, it could be a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution you have there is to reformat your tablet. If there's a way you could connect your tablet to a computer, then try to back up everything like your photos. The apps will really be deleted so you have to manually download them again from the app store.

Your problem shows that there's a problem with recognizing the SD card. There's also another option which is to check if the SD card you used was really okay and not broken or damaged. Try to insert it into another device and see if it will be recognized or if you could save anything to it. If yes, then the problem is with your tablet that needs reformatting. If not, then try to replace your sd card and try again.